# Is cobol declarative language or its is imperative

Tags: cobol, declarative, imperative-programming

while COBOL does support some declarative programming constructs, it is primarily an imperative programming language that is designed to provide low-level control over the machine, and its main focus is on describing how a program should operate, rather than what it should accomplish.so either it is example of declarative or imperative or both

Clarify me whether it is declarative imperative or both

Comment: COBOL is an imperative language.

Answer (score 1):

It is an imperative language; you write instructions that you wish the code to execute.